# Mongoose nested arrays of schema updates

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Shocker, I'm new to Mongo/Mongoose. From my reading/understanding of Mongo its better to use nested documents instead of normalizing all data into separate documents.  With that in mind I have the following schema:

```
var RowSchema = new Schema({
  value: String
});

var ColumnSchema = new Schema({
  title:  String,
  rows: [RowSchema]
});

var ThingSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    'default': shortid.generate
  },
  name: String,
  startTime: Date,
  endTime: Date,
  columns: [ColumnSchema]
  active: Boolean
});
```

From a UI I'm trying to simply add a RowSchema, within a Column/Thing Schema.  My understanding with Mongo is that you usually work with the **WHOLE** top level document. In my UI I have an instance of ThingSchema, which I was manipulating rows (push etc.), to directly manipulate the entire document. When sending the new version of the document back to be updated I've found my understanding is apparently incorrect.

At first I tried to update as any other document:

```
    exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  Retrospective.findById(req.params.id, function (err, thing) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(! thing) { return res.send(404); }
    var updated = _.merge(thing, req.body);
    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, thing);
    });
  });
};
```

But alas, after viewing many articles I don't believe this whole document replace will work?  I've read about using the $push or $addToSet (which work) and even tried  hacky stuff like (which also works) but feels dirty:

```
thing.columns[1].rows.push(fromWire.columns[1].rows[fromWire.columns[1].rows.length-1]);
thing.save(function (err) {
  if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
  return res.json(200, retrospective);
});
```

I'm nervous about having the backend controlling the push/pop indexing of these array items as the UI will be able to move the indexes around in the array and it seems like i'm setting my self up for failure.  What are the best practices for this?  Should not be thinking in terms of whole document replacement? Should I just get used to updating sub documents??  It seems like a data consistency nightmare as many clients need to receive updated copies every edit.

Thanks!